# Meteor and jQuery ConnectedSortable Lists: "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'"

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor, jquery-ui-sortable, meteor-blaze

Using Meteor 1.0, two lists – connected via *jQuery Sortable* – work normally while dragging and dropping Items onto different Lists.

Except when dragging the **last Item** from a List and dropping it to **first or middle position** in the new list:

**"Exception in queued task: Error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on
'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a
child of this node."**

Dropping it as 'last' works.

I gather it might be Meteor's Blaze conflicting with jQuery, but any hints are much appreciated. The error message in the console:

[image]

Complete trace:

```
 at Error (native)
 at DOMRange.attach (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77…)
 at DOMRange.setMembers (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77…)
 at DOMRange.removeMember (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77…)
 at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77…
 at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?19…)
 at Object.eachView.stopHandle.ObserveSequence.observe.removedAt (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77…)
 at Object.cursor.observe.removedAt (http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?2f…)
 at observeChangesCallbacks.removed (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?9a…)
 at Object.self.applyChange.removed (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?9a…)
```

**The code:**

list_items.jade

```
ul.tasks.sortable
   each tasks
     |{{ >taskItem }}
   else
     |There are no tasks yet.
```

task_item.jade

```
template(name="taskItem")
  li.task.item
    .inner
      .title
        |{{ title }}
      .date.light-text on {{ created }}
      strong list: {{ listId }}
      small rank: {{ rank }}
```

list_item.coffee

```
Template.listItem.helpers
  'tasks': ->
    currentUserId = Meteor.userId()
    Tasks.find
      userId: currentUserId
      listId: this._id
    ,
      sort:
        rank: 1

Template.listItem.rendered = ->
  @$(".tasks.sortable").sortable
    placeholder: "task-placeholder"
    connectWith: ".tasks.sortable"
    tolerance: "pointer"

    start: (e, ui) ->
      item = ui.item
      parent = ui.item.parent().get(0)
      listId = Blaze.getData(parent)._id
      newList = oldList = listId
      return

    stop: (e, ui) ->
      el = ui.item.get(0)
      parent = ui.item.parent().get(0)
      listId = Blaze.getData(parent)._id

    # Dragged within same list
    if listId == oldList
      console.log "same"
      before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
      after = ui.item.next().get(0)
      if before    
        if after
          newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank + Blaze.getData(before).rank) / 2
        else
          newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1
      else if after
        newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1

    # Dragged to new list
    else
      console.log "*NEW*"
      if Tasks.find({listId: listId}).count() == 0
        newRank = 1
      else
        before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
        after = ui.item.next().get(0)
      if before    
        if after
          newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank + Blaze.getData(before).rank) / 2
        else
          newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1
      else if after
        newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1


    console.log "Moved " + Blaze.getData(el)._id + " from " + oldList + " to " + listId

    #update the dragged Item's rank
    Tasks.update
      _id: Blaze.getData(el)._id
    ,
      $set:
        listId: listId
        rank: newRank
```

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: added the source, thanks for checking

Comment: I am having the same issue. When dragging the last item out of a sortable list, I get this error. And the empty folder list item is not shown.